# What is the use of devTrees while training stanford sentiment model?

Tags: stanford-nlp

While training the stanford sentiment model for a given dataset, we are using the command:

```
 java -mx8g edu.stanford.nlp.sentiment.SentimentTraining -numHid 25 -trainPath train.txt -devPath dev.txt -train -model model.ser.gz
```

Is it possible to train without using dev.txt? What is its significance?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to train without using development data. The development data is used to evaluate the model on "unseen" test data, to guess at how well the final model will generalize to new inputs.

If you don't provide any development data, you won't be able to get any feedback during training on the performance of your model. (You can still take the saved models and test on new data manually.)

Comment: Thank you. I would also like to know how do you find the accuracy of the sentiment model after evaluating it against the test dataset. In the evaluation summary,there are two things: label accuracy and root label accuracy. What is the difference between them. How do you find the overall accuracy?

Comment: Label accuracy measures the accuracy of sentiment labels at every node in every tree, while root label accuracy examines only the overall sentiment label. You need to choose the metric that best fits your task. For example, if you don't care about getting exact correctness below the sentence level as long as the sentence-level sentiment is produced correctly, you should probably focus on root label accuracy.

Comment: Right now I am training a dataset of 27328 sentences . But my root label accuracy is only 33 percent when I am testing it against a known dataset of 1794 sentences. What might be the problem? Is it related to the sentence length?

Comment: That does seem low.. how are you monitoring for training convergence? You may need to train the model for a longer time before testing. (Using a dev set will help you know when to stop here!)

Comment: Actually I was using sentiment.ser.gz model file to train inspite of model.ser.gz. That's why the accuracy was low. I am using a dataset which has only training set. How can I build a dev set from that?

Comment: Randomly draw ~1500 examples (to match the test set size) from your training examples. This will be your dev set. Train on the remaining 27328 - 1500 examples.

Comment: Will it make a big difference if I use only training set. How will the root label accuracy change with dev set?

Comment: Also, in your last but one comment, you had mentioned about training convergence. Can you give me some thoughts into this?

Comment: With the amount of training data you have, cutting some thousand sentences off for a development set hopefully won't make a difference in the training process itself. The use of a validation / development set is to provide you with a window into how well your model is doing during training. Without this, you have no idea as to when you should stop training / whether the model is really ready for production use.

Comment: Thank you Jon. I have one more doubt.Does the root label accuracy depend on the number of positive,negative and neutral sentences in the training dataset? Is the  training efficient if I have 69% positive ,25% negative and 5% neutral sentences? I have 29137 sentences out of which 20090 are positive,7339 are negative and 1708 are neutral. Can I benchmark the results based on this data?

Comment: This is only a problem if the distribution of the root labels in the test distribution is different. (Training should match test in all senses!)

Comment: A good baseline would be Naive Bayes (Google for implementations or packages to train and test an NB algorithm).